# Can any React app be deployed to Netlify?

Tags: reactjs, cloud, web-deployment, web-hosting, netlify

I am having trouble understanding the concept of static and dynamic sites within the context of a React app. I am reading about how you can deploy React apps to Netlify which is known for hosting static sites. But all the React apps I've made make requests to Node/Express backends and shows the data that gets returned from them. I'm pretty sure that would make my React apps dynamic. Does this mean that I wouldn't be able to deploy them to Netlify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be able to host the frontend part on Netlify that makes request to a backend elsewhere. But you won't be able to host the backend on Netlify, unless you convert it into serverless functions.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to host the frontend on Netlify then if it had to make requests to a backend elsewhere? Because wouldn't that make the site dynamic and I thought Netlify was useful for static websites right?

Comment: Frontend requests are issued from your visitor's browsers from all over the world. In that regards, it doesn't matter if your frontend and backend are hosted on the same server/location. It's actually preferably to host the frontend as close to the end visitor as possible through CDN hosting at edges, which Netlify does. Netlify is predominantly marketed for static websites but it's fine to host any frontend with it, static or dynamic. Depending on your code workflow, it might make deployments a bit more tricky with separate frontend/backends. But that's about it afaik.

Answer (score 1):

```
let api = ""
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" && "serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  //production
  API = "https://project-sprint.herokuapp.com";
} else {
  //development
  API = "http://localhost:3001";

}
/
```

/ after i concat endpoint complement with this base, then no problem when i deploy